# vagrant up でゲストOSのCentOSを起動させようとすると、ホストOSのMacが再起動してしまう

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox

全くの初心者で独学なので質問内容はご了承ください。
今回やった内容は

```
$ cd
$ mkdir MyVagrant
$ cd MyVagrant
$ mkdir mycentos
$ cd mycentos
$ vagrant init bento/centos-6.7
$ vi Vagrantfile
$ vagrant up`
```

です。

Vagrantfileの編集内容は下の
 `# config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"`
を
  `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"`
にして
`:wq`を使って保存しただけです。

```rb
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "chef/centos-6.5"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
end`
```

です。

v‌​agrant up 後の画面表示内容は途中で再起動してコピーできなかったのですが、似た文章をネットからもってきました。文章内容は恐らく違うと思います。

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
default: 22 => 2223 (adapter 1)
default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
default: SSH username: vagrant
default: SSH auth method: private key
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
default: /vagrant => C:/vagrant/myHost
```

[`==> default: Booting VM...`]
この文だけは覚えているのですけど、ここで落ちて再起動されます。
エラー文も無しでした。

「ドットインストール」というプログラミング学習サイトを参考にしています。

[#04 VagrantでCentOSを立ち上げよう](http://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_localdev_mac/30704)

vagrant ver1.8.1, VirtualBox ver 4.3.20, OSは OSX Yosemite ver 10.10.3 です。 メモリも十分あると思います。
ご協力をお願いします。

Comment: 参考にしたドットインストールのレッスン名やURLは追記できますか？仮想環境作成ツールはvirtual box で合ってますでしょうか？`Booting VM...`で本当に先に進まないのだとすると、vagrantではなくゲストOS側(この例ではcentOSですね)自体に何かあるかもしれないです。普通はゲストOSが起動して、その後vagrantの側からSSHでログインを何回か試そうとするはずです。でもそのログイン試行にまでいかないとなると、vagrantだけを見ていても何がどうなっているのか分からない可能性があります。色々可能性がでてくるので、やはり`vagrant up` 実行時の画面表示を何とか得られるのが望ましいのですが…

Comment: 何が再起動してしまうのか書かれていませんが、ホスト環境であるMacが突然再起動してしまうのでしょうか？

Comment: ドットインストールのレッスン名とURL, VirtualBoxのバージョンを(編集)最後の方に載せておきました。
Mac自体が再起動されてしまいます。

Comment: vagrant upしただけで、ホストOSのMacが再起動??...たしかにそれはお困りでしょうね…訳が分かりません。

Comment: Kernel Panic because of "vagrant up"(https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7253021?start=0&tstart=0)症状としては、これと同じか似てたりしませんでしょうか？
これはvagrant up後MACがカーネルパニックを起こしてリブートするという例です。

Comment: あと、Vagrantfileに`config.vm.boot_mode = :gui`を入れてみてください。これをすると、ゲストOSがGUIモードで起動するはずなので、起動時のメッセージで何か見ることができるかもしれません。

Comment: 途中で再起動してしまうのであれば保存に失敗するかもしれませんが `vagrant up > log.txt` でうまくいけば起動時のログファイルが残ると思います。`mycentos`ディレクトリの中に`log.txt`があればそれを貼り付けてください。
その方法でできないのであれば再起動する直前の画面をスマホのカメラで撮って画像で添付してみてください。何かわかるかもしれません。